# SQL Server 2012: stored procedure creates two ID's

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple insert by a stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertPicture]
    @ProdID INT,
    @Dokart INT,
    @PictDescID INT,
    @PictureDescription NVARCHAR(100),
    @PictureName NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NewID INT

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.tblArtikelbilder(ProdID, Dokart, PictDescID, PictureDescription, PictureName) 
        VALUES (@ProdID, @Dokart, @PictDescID, @PictureDescription, @PictureName)

        SELECT @NewID = @@identity  -- also tried  set @NewID=SCOPE_IDENTITY 
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[tblArtikel] 
        SET PicID = @NewID 
        WHERE ProdID = @ProdID
    END

    BEGIN
        SELECT PicID 
        FROM [dbo].[tblArtikel] 
        WHERE ProdID = @ProdID
    END
END
```

The strange thing is, that the `UPDATE` is correct but the `SELECT` does not return the `PicID` which should be the last inserted ID.

Further, and this leads to an PK violation error (as the `PictureName` is the PK of `tblArtikelbilder`), the ID "jumps" often but not on every execution of the stored procedure.

So the sequence of the `PicID` is for example

```
1
3
4
5
7
```

I cannot find, why there is obviously a failed insert. I always insert just one record, because the parameter `@ProdID` is unique, same with `@PictureName`.

It looks like the stored procedure runs twice.

It is only running on my dev machine, no other user runs any inserting of rows in any table.

Michael

Comment: You definitely do not want to use @@IDENTITY. Go back to using SCOPE_IDENTITY. If you have a trigger you will get the wrong value. You also don't need to put BEGIN/END blocks all over the place. I would remove all of those, but they don't affect the outcome here, they are just noise.

Comment: Seems like something is a little off here. You are inserting what appears to be a child row for an Artikel and then updating the parent row with the value of the child? Can you share the ddl of these two tables and some sample data to represent the issue?